# Can I write a python/SQL code that is independent of the sql engine (PostGres / Sqlite)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite, psycopg2

I have a python code, in which I make SQL requests in a database. I would like to be able to switch between a postgresql (using module psycopg2) database and a sqlite one (using module sqlite3), without need of adapting my code. This means, I would like to have in my code some fixed SQL request strings, and I want to switch between the engine, only changing the definition of the database connector object, using one of those:

- `my_db = psycopg2.connect(...)`
- `my_db = sqlite3.connect(...)`

For the moment, I don't see any possibilty since:

1. Everyone knows that one should NOT use string concatenation to pass arguments to a SQL request, but rather use placeholders (from psycopg2 docu :*never, NEVER use Python string concatenation ... to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at **gunpoint**.* )
2. The synthax for placeholders are different is the 2 APIs psycopg2 and sqlite3. Even for NON-named placeholders. Psycopg uses "%" and sqlite3 uses "?":

   - `my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?", (my_id,))  # for SQLITE3`
   - `my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= %", (my_id,))  # for PSYCOPG2`
3. One could in principle use the SQL built-in placeholder synthax ("?"
   for postgresql), but this would mean precisely preparing a SQL-string with python string concatenation, and so on... that is forbidden by 1.

I'm lacking ideas...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the viable database abstraction layers for Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679806/what-are-the-viable-database-abstraction-layers-for-python)

Comment: Database abstraction layers (DAL) does just like that.

Comment: I find, that using a big machinery like SQL-alchemy, just to handle the different placeholders ? vs %, is a bit exagerated... but maybe there is no other solution...

Comment: Postgres & SQLite differs a lot apart from their placeholders in python. F.ex. they have some different data-types, SQL features are not supported on the same level, etc. If you are willing to use these dbs (and probably even more) you'll effectively write a database abstraction layer by definition.